# Qt Cygwin/g++ Makefile error when compiling

Tags: qt, makefile, cmake, g++, cygwin

Hi I am trying to get Qt to work with Visual Studio 2015 Community edition and when I go to the command prompt and use the following command c:\Qt\5.6.0\qbase\configure I get the following ugly looking error:

```
Creating qmake...
g++ -c -o project.o -DUNICODE -ffunction-sections -g  -

IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/library -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/generators -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/generators/unix -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/generators/win32 -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/generators/mac -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/generators/integrity -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase\include -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase\include/QtCore -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase\include/QtCore/5.6.0 -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase\include/QtCore/5.6.0/QtCore -I../src/corelib/global -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++ -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/tools/shared -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DPROEVALUATOR_FULL -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_CRYPTOGRAPHICHASH_ONLY_SHA1 -DQT_JSON_READONLY -DQT_NO_STANDARDPATHS C:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/project.cpp
    g++: error: spawn: Exec format error
    Makefile:202: recipe for target 'project.o' failed
    mingw32-make: *** [project.o] Error 1
    rm -f project.o option.o property.o main.o ioutils.o proitems.o qmakevfs.o qmakeglobals.o qmakeparser.o qmakeevaluator.o qmakebuiltins.o makefile.o unixmake2.o unixmake.o mingw_make.o winmakefile.o projectgenerator.o meta.o makefiledeps.o metamakefile.o xmloutput.o pbuilder_pbx.o msvc_vcproj.o msvc_vcxproj.o msvc_nmake.o msvc_objectmodel.o msbuild_objectmodel.o cesdkhandler.o qtextcodec.o qutfcodec.o qstring.o qstring_compat.o qstringbuilder.o qtextstream.o qiodevice.o qringbuffer.o qdebug.o qmalloc.o qglobal.o qarraydata.o qbytearray.o qbytearraymatcher.o qdatastream.o qbuffer.o qlist.o qfiledevice.o qfile.o qfilesystementry.o qfilesystemengine.o qfsfileengine.o qfsfileengine_iterator.o qregexp.o qvector.o qbitarray.o qdir.o qdiriterator.o quuid.o qhash.o qfileinfo.o qdatetime.o qstringlist.o 

qabstractfileengine.o qtemporaryfile.o qmap.o qmetatype.o qsettings.o qsystemerror.o qlibraryinfo.o qvariant.o qvsnprintf.o qlocale.o qlocale_tools.o qlinkedlist.o qnumeric.o qcryptographichash.o qxmlstream.o qxmlutils.o qlogging.o qjson.o qjsondocument.o qjsonparser.o qjsonarray.o qjsonobject.o qjsonvalue.o qfilesystemengine_win.o qfilesystemiterator_win.o qfsfileengine_win.o qlocale_win.o qsettings_win.o qsystemlibrary.o registry.o
    g++ -c -o project.o -DUNICODE -ffunction-sections -g  -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/library -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/generators -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/generators/unix -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/generators/win32 -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/generators/mac -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/generators/integrity -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase\include -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase\include/QtCore -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase\include/QtCore/5.6.0 -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase\include/QtCore/5.6.0/QtCore -I../src/corelib/global -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++ -IC:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/tools/shared -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DPROEVALUATOR_FULL -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_CRYPTOGRAPHICHASH_ONLY_SHA1 -DQT_JSON_READONLY -DQT_NO_STANDARDPATHS C:\Qt\5.6.0\qtbase/qmake/project.cpp
    g++: error: spawn: Exec format error
Makefile:202: recipe for target 'project.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [project.o] Error 1
Building qmake failed, return code 2
On a related note when I just run Qt it will not compile anything also.
```

Thanks folks!!!!

Comment: "I am trying to get Qt to work with Visual Studio 2015 Community edition” - if you want to use msvc, don’t try building it in cygwin with g++, those don’t mix. Use a standard command prompt and source vcvarsall.bat.

Comment: ok so this is going to sound like a stupid question but how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Use cmake from cygwin. Please note however that Qt is already available in Cygwin both QT4 and Qt5, so you don't need to build them

Comment: I am sorry to be a bother but I honestly do not understand what you are suggesting

Comment: Question: why do you need to build QT ?